# fading scrollbar when not scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, scrollbar

I recently started making a little website project and I'm struggling a bit with customizing my scrollbar.

I got so far that the scrollbar is only visible when you hover over it but that's not exactly my goal. I want it to be hidden when the user didn't scroll for a certain period of time. This is what I got so far:

```
<style>

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 6px;
        height: 12px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0);
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    /*Commented because I don't want it to show when I just hover the site
    body:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    */


    body.scrolling::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal:hover,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover {
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }


    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal:active,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:active {
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
</style>

<script>$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('body').addClass('scrolling');
    alert("!!");
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').removeClass('scrolling');
    }, 250));
});</script>
```

This is my first post on a forum like this so please just tell me if I have to provide more info and which info is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its just a typo. Change the closing style tag to `</style>`. It can't be tested very well if theres an alert popping up every time you scroll. Remove `alert("!!");` or change it to `console.log("!!");`

[LATER]

As you want the scrollbar to fade in and out with a transition, you'll have to use an element that covers it and animate its opacity. It's not possible to put an element above the document's scrollbar though. That's why you have to wrap the whole page inside a div and customize its scrollbar.

```js
document.querySelector('.scroll-box').addEventListener('scroll', hideCoverBar);
document.querySelector('.scroll-box').addEventListener('mousemove', hideCoverBar);
var showTimeout;
function hideCoverBar() {
  document.querySelector('.cover-bar').classList.add('hidden');
  clearTimeout(showTimeout);
  showTimeout = setTimeout(showCoverBar, 1000);

}
function showCoverBar() {
  document.querySelector('.cover-bar').classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.main {
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scroll-bar-wrap {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: .4em;
}

.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar,
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  overflow: visible;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.cover-bar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: .4em;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.cover-bar.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-bar-wrap">
        <div class="scroll-box">
            <div class="main">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                </h1>
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/400" />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cover-bar"></div>
    </div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/71fjr0Lz/

Comment: The alert isnt even coming up tho :c but the tag might be the problem

Comment: Still doesnt work I think it might actually be a js problem

Comment: Did you forget to load jquery? Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your jquery code is getting executed.

Comment: wait does order matter when "importing" scripts??

Comment: ohh thanks i still dont get how i can have the scrollbar fade in and or out

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uxr5fLzm/ 
- When there's no mouse inside the body, the scrollbar is completely hidden. 
- If there is a mouse inside the body, it has an opacity of 0.3. 
- If the user hovers the scrollbar or scrolls the page, it has an opacity of 1.

Comment: i did achieve that too but my goal is to have it animate the fade in/out i tried `-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;` but it doesnt do anything

Comment: Normal transitions won't work. You'll have to use an element that covers the scrollbar and fade that one... https://codepen.io/rtcoms/pen/rVeLwX

Comment: Ok so now i have a bar apearing and disapearing whenever i scroll but its not covering the sccroll bar its perfectly to the left of it. I figured it may be due to me editing the basic scroll bar but i cant rly figure how to get the scroll bar on the div.
this is an updated version of my code so far: https://pastebin.com/RzgmQcMa

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please use the code from the answer and place your own content inside the `.main` div.